# Rails.application.routes.recognize_path with devise authenticated route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a devise enabled route as:

```
#config/routes.rb
authenticated :user {
  root :to => 'home#signed_in'
}
root :to => 'home#index
```

and controller:

```
#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def signed_in
    Rails.application.routes.recognize_path '/'
  end
end
```

which raises:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
...lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:286:in `block in authenticated'
```

I need such thing to render different templates in destroy action based on `request.referer` controller name. How can get 'authenticated' controller/action name for such URL?

Comment: Use :users instead of :user

Answer (score 1):

It seems using `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` does not work well with custom routes constraints like devise `#authenticated` method.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3747

> recognize_path won't work as is with constraints that require request related objects (like the warden instance that Devise expects to be in the request env Hash). If you are doing this inside a controller code you might be able to pass the warden object from request.env to the recognize_path call, or try to pass down the object down the the class that is recognizing the path.
>
> In the other hand, as recognize_path isn't a documented public API, I strongly suggest you to not use it and save pieces of the params Hash instead of the raw URL on your application.

One solution to your problem could be to save the controller/action names in session and access them when you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#signed_in'
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
```

Comment: I do want to get 'authenticated' route, so adding 'unauthenticated' doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: https://gist.github.com/NullVoxPopuli/8c8af217b7404336c72a

```
class RouteRecognizer
  include Singleton

  ROUTE_LIST = Rails.application.routes.routes.collect{|r| r.path.spec.to_s}
  REGEX_ROUT_LIST = ROUTE_LIST.map{|r|
    Regexp.new(r.gsub(/\:(.*)id/, "(\d+)").gsub("(.:format)", ""))
  }

  def self.is_route?(path)
    REGEX_ROUT_LIST.each do |regex|
      return true if !!(path =~ regex)
    end
    false
 end
end
```

and then call with

```
RouteRecognizer.is_route?('http://whatever')
```